# JavaScript Regex Match All from Array

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to search a string and find multiple matches at once from an array.

I joined my array items with `'|'`, but I'm getting `null`.

```
var searchTerms = ['dog', 'cat'];
var str = 'I have a dog and a cat';

// want to return matches for both dog and cat
console.log(str.match('/' + searchTerms.join('|') + '/g'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duDP9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object from a string you need to use the [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Constructor):

```
console.log(str.match(new RegExp(searchTerms.join('|'), 'g')));
```

However, I'd generally recommend some other approach. If your search terms contain a special regex character (e.g. `$`), then this is likely to fail. Of course you could escape those special characters, but still, I'd recommend you look for some other solution if possible.

It's hard to say exactly what solution would look like, since I don't know the full use case, but here's a very simple example of an alternative solution:

```
var str = 'I have a dog and a cat';
var searchTerms = {'dog': 1, 'cat': 1};
console.log(str.split(/\s+/).filter(function(x) { return x in searchTerms; }));
// [ "dog", "cat" ]
```

Comment: could you make a recommendation on "some other approach" :D

Comment: @user3448187 See my updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: very, very interesting. If the string is very long, would you say regex is faster?

Comment: @user3448187 Well, it might be faster, it might be slower. That depends on a lot of factors. In any case if it's *really* long, I would probably try to do a lot of this processing on the server, possibly with something like a [full-text search in SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: thanks! It's not that long, I'm just a little paranoid on performance for some strange reason. :D I'll keep digging around with breaking the string up into words

Comment: @p.s.w.g I would upvote for all the effort but I don't have 15 rep :). I'm going to be using this method as it's better for my circumstance.

Answer (score 5):

Use `RegExp` like this:

```
var searchTerms = ['dog', 'cat'];
var str = 'I have a dog and a cat';

console.log(str.match(new RegExp(searchTerms.join('|'), 'g')));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), along with [`Str.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which returns `-1` if the string isn't found:

```
var searchTerms = ['dog', 'cat'];
var str = 'I have a dog and a cat';
searchTerms.every(search => str.indexOf(search) !== -1);
// true
str = 'I only have a dog';
searchTerms.every(search => str.indexOf(search) !== -1);
// false
```

`Array.every` returns `true` if the callback returns `true` for every element of the array.

The advantage of using this approach over regular expressions is that there is less chance that characters in your `searchTerms` will be interpreted in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to regular expression using `new RegExp(..., 'g')`

```
console.log(str.match(new RegExp(searchTerms.join('|'), 'g')));
```

Comment: this only returns `cat` for me

Comment: @user3448187, `'/' +` should be removed. I updated the answer. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of what you want to do is `(option1|option2|...|optionN)` watch out the parentheses, I don't think you've added them.

Try to use: `console.log(str.match('/(' + searchTerms.join('|') + ')/g'));`